# How to add an Icon in popupmenu using codes in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a button that can generate a sql table and also a button in popupmenu bar, but I couldn't add an image on it.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DevExpress.XtraBars;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;


namespace Fifth_Attempt
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form
    {
        private DevExpress.XtraBars.BarManager barManager1;
        private DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu buttonContextMenu;
        DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem menuButtonExport = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem();
        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            barManager1 = new BarManager();
            this.barManager1.Form = this;
            buttonContextMenu = new DevExpress.XtraBars.PopupMenu(barManager1);
            this.buttonContextMenu.Name = "subViewContextMenu";


            menuButtonExport.Caption = ""+txtTblName.Text+"";
            menuButtonExport.Id = 1;
            menuButtonExport.Name = "btn"+txtTblName.Text+"";
            menuButtonExport.Images = DevExpress.Images.ImageResourceCache.Default.GetImage(ModelEditor_Views);
            //add items to barmanager
            this.barManager1.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItem[] {
            menuButtonExport
            });
            //create links between bar items and popup
            buttonContextMenu.ItemLinks.Add(barManager1.Items["btn"+txtTblName.Text+""]);
            //finally set the context menu to the control or use the showpopup method on right click of control
            barManager1.SetPopupContextMenu(btnCreate, buttonContextMenu);
        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + txtTblName.Text + " (LRN int (50), FirstName nvarchar (50), MiddleName nvarchar (50), LastName nvarchar (50), Gender nvarchar (50), Understanding nvarchar (50), Contemporary nvarchar (50), PE nvarchar (50), Research nvarchar (50), Net nvarchar (50), Oracle nvarchar (50), Media nvarchar (50));", conn);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the image/icon are not showing..
Anyone can help me to add an icon?